# Python byte array for Serial communication

Tags: java, python, c++, arrays

i got a program which needs to send a byte array via a serial communication. And I got no clue how one can make such a thing in python.
I found a c/c++/java function which creates the needed byte array:

```
byte[] floatArrayToByteArray(float[] input)
{
  int len = 4*input.length;
  int index=0;
  byte[] b = new byte[4];
  byte[] out = new byte[len];
  ByteBuffer buf = ByteBuffer.wrap(b);
  for(int i=0;i<input.length;i++) 
  {
    buf.position(0);
    buf.putFloat(input[i]);
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++) out[j+i*4]=b[3-j];
  }
  return out;
}
```

but how can I translate that to python code.
edit: the serial data is send to a device. where I can not change the firmware.
thanks

Comment: That looks like Java code, not C++

Comment: Must it be `bytearrays`, or can it be `bytes`?  If `bytes` is ok you probably want the [`struct`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/struct.html) module.

Comment: Also it would be good to have sample input/output.

Comment: it might be java sry. well since the code has to be send to a device which expects exactly that format it has to be that byte array

Answer (score 2):

Put your data to array (here are [0,1,2] ), and send with: serial.write(). I assume you've properly opened serial port.

```
>> import array
>> tmp = array.array('B', [0x00, 0x01, 0x02]).tostring()
>> ser.write(tmp.encode())
```

Ansvered using: [Binary data with pyserial(python serial port)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/472977/binary-data-with-pyserialpython-serial-port)
and this:[pySerial write() won't take my string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275079/pyserial-write-wont-take-my-string)

Comment: Thank you.  This helped me.  However, I had to remove the call to "encode"; it was not recognized.  I just passed the array.  I don't know -- maybe it has to do with different versions of Python.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you are sending a signed or unsigned and other parameters. There is a bunch of documentation on this. This is an example I have used in the past.

```
x1= 0x04
x2 = 0x03
x3 = 0x02
x4 = x1+ x2+x3
input_array = [x1, x2, x3, x4]
write_bytes = struct.pack('<' + 'B' * len(input_array),  *input_array) 
ser.write(write_bytes)
```

To understand why I used 'B' and '<' you have to refer to pyserial documentation.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html